# Error while bundle install

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am new to ruby on rails and i'm following ["Ruby on Rails Tutorial: Learn Rails by Example"](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321743121) from Michael Hartl in the 2nd online edition.

When i run a `bundle install` from my rails app it shows error like this

```
Gem::RemoteFetcher::FetchError: too many connection resets (http://cachefly.mirrors.rubygems.org/gems/rubyzip-0.9.7.gem)
An error occured while installing rubyzip (0.9.7), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install rubyzip -v '0.9.7'` succeeds before bundling.
```

I'm trying these from yesterday night but no result some people say its my internet problem but internet is working fine.

Comment: Could you add some information to the Ruby version, Gems version and Rails version you are using?

Comment: ruby 1.9.3p125 (2012-02-16) [i386-mingw32]

Answer (score 3):

If you search for `ruby gem "too many connection resets"`, you will find a lot of references. The team is currently not able to track it down. These are the reasons:

- Trying to build a gem and push it to GitHub. This is fixed lately and has nothing to do with your case.
- [RubyGems.org](http://rubygems.org/) has network problems, which you cannot fix. You should try to do a `bundle install` later.
- Follow the tip in the error message, and install first rubyzip by doing: `gem install rubyzip -v '0.9.7'`. After that has succeeded, continue with `bundle install` (which will just use your installed rubyzip then).