# Ruby gem install sass error

Tags: sass, rubygems, compass-sass

I want to install sass and I have the same problem as [Error installing gem install sass](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28589251/error-installing-gem-install-sass-windows-7). This is what I get when I try to get the resources:

```
C:\Ruby22-x64>gem sources -a http://rubygems.org/
https://rubygems.org is recommended for security over http://rubygems.org/

Do you want to add this insecure source? [yn]  y
Error fetching http://rubygems.org/:
        too many connection resets (http://rubygems.global.ssl.fastly.net/specs.4.8.gz)
```

What should I do? Is there any way to get the resources and install them manually?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10278174/gem-not-installing-showing-connection-error, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10267824/error-while-bundle-install, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by downloading and installed it manually